# Watch coffee files and only want to use filename as target

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, watch

**My folder structure**

```
app/tool_1/js/myfile.coffee
app/tool_2/js/myfile2.coffee
```

...

I want to compile these files to one directory:

```
server/jsfolder/
```

**Gruntfile.coffee**

```
module.exports = ( grunt ) ->
    grunt.initConfig
        watch:
            tools_coffee:
                files: [ "app/**/*.coffee" ]
                tasks: [ "newer:coffee:tools" ]


        coffee:
            tools:
                expand: true
                cwd: "app"
                src: [ "**/*.coffee" ]
                dest: "server/jsfolder"
                ext: ".js"
```

Problem

The whole path will be copied to dest:

```
server/jsfolder/tool_1/js/myfile.js
```

The result I want is like:

```
server/jsfolder/myfile.js
```

Is there any solution for this?

I use grunt-newer and grunt-watch for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is an function rename where the name can be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I believe you want the `flatten` option, which will remove source paths from your dest directory.

rename, to answer your answer, is pretty cool too, and looks like this:

```
 dest: 'foo/',
     rename: function(dest, src) {
         return dest + src.replace('foo', 'bar')
     },
 }
```